# Normal sheaf of the diagonal of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let $\Delta_{\mathbb{P}^1}$ be the diagonal line of $\mathbb{P}^1 \times \mathbb{P}^1$, and $\mathcal{N}_{\Delta_{\mathbb{P}^1}}$ be its normal sheaf.
I heard that $\mathcal{N}_{\Delta_{\mathbb{P}^1}} \simeq T\mathbb{P}^1 \simeq \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(2)$.

My questions are

*1. How can I prove this equality?

 2. Can I think this normal sheaf as
        $(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1) \boxtimes
    \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1))|_{\Delta_{\mathbb{P}^1}}$ ?*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first isomorphism is true for a general scheme (sometimes it is taken as a definition). The second equality follow from either the Euler exact sequence (which generalizes to $P^n$) or from the degree of the canonical bundle and a classification of line bundles on $\mathbb P^1$ which generalizes to curves.

Comment: The answer to (2) is yes. The box product bundle corresponds to divisors of type $(1,1)$ on $\mathbb P^1 \times \mathbb P^1$, and the diagonal is also a divisor of this type. Since the self intersection of this divisor class is $2$, the indicated restriction is $\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not realize that this isomorphism is in fact the definition of (relative) differential (in Hartshorne book). 
Now I understood both questions.